# Why This PHP code Not inserting proper ways

Tags: php, sql-server

Here we go, when i try to Insert my First Query Running and Data Inserted but my Second Query not Working.At the same Time to comment the first Query Second one working good. while both means I am stuck

```
if($order_no!="" && $cus_name!="")
    {
        //fs_code: set primary key into auto means use this qry before inserting
        $query1 = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT order_creation ON";
        $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO order_creation (order_no,cus_name,cus_id,types,created_date,Status,id) VALUES('$order_no','$cus_name','$cus_id','$type',FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'M/d/yyyy h:mm:sstt'),'$Status','$fmax')";

        if(sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql))
            {
                echo 'success-1';
            }
        else
            {
                echo 'failure-1';
            }
    }
for($i=0;$i<count($goods_name);$i++)
    {       
        if($goods_name[$i]!="")
            {                       
                $sql = "INSERT INTO order_Goods (order_no,goods_name,goods_qty,date,created_date,Balance_Qty,Supply_Qty,ProductPrice,id) VALUES('$order_no','$goods_name[$i]','$goods_qty[$i]',FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'d/MM/yy h:mm:sstt'),'$created_date[$i]','$goods_qty[$i]','$Supply_Qty','$ProductPrice[$i]','$get_maxres')";

                if(sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql))
                    {
                        echo 'success-2';
                    }
                else
                    {
                        echo 'failure-2';
                    }
                $get_maxres++;
            }
    }

sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: You're using SQL-Server, why did you tag this with MySQL? Don't you know the difference?

Comment: Sorry Mistake is mine @Barmar and Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the correct syntax to substitute an array value into a string. When the array index contains a variable, you need to use the "complex" syntax, where the array variable is surrounded by `{}`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO order_Goods (order_no,goods_name,goods_qty,date,created_date,Balance_Qty,Supply_Qty,ProductPrice,id)
     VALUES('$order_no','{$goods_name[$i]}','{$goods_qty[$i]}',FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'d/MM/yy h:mm:sstt'),'{$created_date[$i]}','{$goods_qty[$i]}','$Supply_Qty','{$ProductPrice[$i]}','$get_maxres')";
```

See the section **Variable parsing** in the PHP [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) documentation.

You also need to enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` on the second table. Put this before the `for` loop:

```
sqlsrv_query($conn, "SET IDENTITY_INSERT order_creation OFF");
sqlsrv_query($conn, "SET IDENTITY_INSERT order_Goods ON");
```

Comment: Thanks for Response but above the query not fix my problem @Barmar

Comment: Does it say `failure-2`? Use `var_dump(sqlserv_errors($conn))` to see the error.

Comment: yes, failure-2 and where i can place "var_dump(sqlserv_errors($conn))"

Comment: After `echo "failure-2"`.

Comment: i am getting this "boolean false"

Comment: Oops, this function doesn't take `$conn` as an argument. It should be `sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL);`

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '23000' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string '23000' (length=5)
      1 => int 544
      'code' => int 544
      2 => string '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'order_Goods' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.' (length=161)
      'message' => string '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'order_Goods' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.' (length=161)

Comment: what i have get this one

Comment: so i use SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON (its working but first quesry not working )

Comment: You need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT order_Goods ON`.

Comment: What does `sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL)` say there?

Comment: success-1
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '23000' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string '23000' (length=5)
      1 => int 544
      'code' => int 544
      2 => string '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'order_Goods' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.' (length=161)
      'message' => string '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'order_Goods' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.' (length=161)
failure-2

Comment: That says `success-1`, so the first query is working.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying is happening. Which query is working, which query is failing? You shouldn't be getting that error if you enabled `IDENTITY_INSERT` on both tables.

Comment: No , when run this file 1st query working fine, but 2nd not working this is the problem. Now add ON and OFF IDENTITY_INSERT between insert query it will working

Comment: You should not have OFF, just ON for both of them.

Comment: Ahh, I see, this option is only allowed on one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

yes i fix by this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON

INSERT INTO Table1
/*Note the column list is REQUIRED here, not optional*/
            (OperationID,
             OpDescription,
             FilterID)
VALUES      (20,
             'Hierachy Update',
             1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF
```